# How can I use jQuery's replaceWith() function to make a href link trigger a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This is what I've tried:

#### html:

```
<div id="container">
  <p>a paragraph</p>
</div>
<button>replace with link</button>
```

#### script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("a.foo").click(function() {
        alert('hello world');
     });

     function foo() {
        alert('hello world');
     }

     $("button").click(function () {
        // neither of these work
        // $("#container p").replaceWith('<p><a href="#" class="foo" >trigger function<\/a><\/p>');
        // $("#container p").replaceWith('<p><a href="#" onclick="foo();return false" >trigger function<\/a><\/p>');
     });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `live`.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Replace this

```
$("a.foo").click(function() {
        alert('hello world');
});
```

with

```
$("a.foo").live('click', function() {
        alert('hello world');
});
```

and do your replacement like

```
$("#container p").replaceWith('<p><a href="#" class="foo" >trigger function<\/a><\/p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `.replaceWith()`? All you need is `.html()`:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#container p").html('<p><a href="#" class="foo" >trigger function</a></p>');
});
```

Comment: replaceWith replaces the entire matched element, not what's inside it.

Comment: Ah indeed - so strip off the <p> and </p> of my string and it still does what he wants i think

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that the href="#" of the link element causes a postback and the click event might not work properly. On the live event click make sure you prevent that default action from being produced.

```
$(".lnkLike").live("click", function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```